# GraphQL and ApolloProvider and store... its very nested

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo

So, I am passing store thru ApolloProvider

```
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={apolloClient}>
```

Now, ApolloProvider is putting it, the store, in client. But its putting the store object, not the actual reducer object. So, I am getting the following, which seems odd to me..

```
client
   ---> store
  -----------> getState
  -----------> dispatch
```

but no "state"? I mean, sure if I would call getState(), but that seems quite different from when I usually do redux without Apollo. I get my "state tree"... here, I am getting it...

What is the "normal" or "best practices" when using redux w/ graphql?

It seems excessive to access a state prop like so:

```
if (this.props.client.state.getState().whatever.foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use queries to local state and React Hooks like:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
//...
export default () => {
    const { data } = useQuery(gql('query GetTableFilter { selectedMall @client }'));
    // ... do something with data.selectedMall
```